# How can I perform AVRO Diff (Difference between 2 AVRO files) in python

Tags: python, avro

This question has been answered here to some extent: [Is there anyway to compare two avro files to see what differences exist in the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351017/is-there-anyway-to-compare-two-avro-files-to-see-what-differences-exist-in-the-d)

However, I want to check if there is any simpler way to create a function in Python that takes two AVRO files, compare them and determine if they are same or different. I understand that the schemas need to be checked and then the contents.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a pre-created library that will compare to Avro objects but there are plenty out there that can do JSON.  For instance you can use Jackson in java (https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-compare-two-json-objects) or you can use deepdiff in python (https://pypi.org/project/deepdiff/).  You can just deserialize the AVRO into JSON and apply one of these.

Like Jijo said, however, it kind of depends on where you are running this and what your performance requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

--> Where are you trying to run this program ? 
--> is it in a cluster where hive/pig is installed ?
      if you are able to load both the files in to a pigscript , 
      group by and count of each line == 2 should help you as they are same or not.

if its not a cluster -- i will fall back to java to use avroutil jar read the files and start iterating the records. [ I am not sure about the scalability of the data files in this approach ]

The best way is using hive / pig in your wrapper program to compare the data is efficient and scalable.